# Armorstand Teleporting After Reloging(Spigot)

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Why does my armorstand teleport after relogging into my server? For example, before relogging: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa9Si.jpg, and after relogging: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hoq4.jpg. I'm trying to make it so the armorstand will teleport once you right click a bone without having to relog.

Here's my Main code:

```
package com.jason.sbitems;

import com.jason.sbitems.bows.Bonemerang;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class SBItems extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Bonemerang(), this);
        ItemManager.init();
        getCommand("get").setExecutor(new GetCommand());
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[SBItems Plugin]: Plugin is Enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getServer().getConsoleSender().sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "[SBItems Plugin]: Plugin is Disabled!");
    }
}
```

Here's my class code:

```
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.entity.ArmorStand;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.block.Action;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerInteractEvent;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.util.EulerAngle;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;

public class Bonemerang implements Listener {
    @EventHandler
    public static void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();

        if (e.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR) {
            if (p.getInventory().getItemInMainHand().equals(new ItemStack(Material.BONE))) {
                ArmorStand stand = (ArmorStand) p.getWorld().spawnEntity(p.getLocation(), EntityType.ARMOR_STAND);
                Vector teleportTo = p.getLocation().getDirection().normalize().multiply(10);

                stand.hasArms();
                stand.setGravity(false);
                stand.setItemInHand(new ItemStack(Material.BONE));
                stand.setRightArmPose(new EulerAngle(Math.toRadians(0), Math.toRadians(120), Math.toRadians(0)));
                stand.teleport(p.getLocation().add(teleportTo));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, is there a way to make it so that it will teleport after 10 seconds?

Comment: My best bet would be that the armor stand is only teleporting server side so the client still sees it as the wrong location, does relogging again do anything? Plus stand.hasArms() returns a boolean so that line is pointless.

Comment: Nope, relogging once updates the armorstand position and another time doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yes, its definitely only server side then. Try using NMS to teleport it? Spigot has a discord that can help you, discord.gg/spigotmc i think

Comment: What is NMS?(I'm kinda new to Spigot API)

Comment: NMS is net MInecraft server, and its when you directly access classes, and in this case packets, of Minecraft.

Comment: Okay I will do some research on that. Thank you!